# Match key word in list of strings to variables

Tags: python

I am reading all files from a directory and storing the file paths of those in that directory in a list using

```
files = [os.path.abspath(x) for x in os.listdir(r"my directory")]
```

Each file in a unique template so the resulting list is something like

```
[C:\Users\....\Template_Coversheet.xlsx
C:\Users\....\Template_Blanks.xlsx,
C:\Users\....\Template_Stocks.xlsx,
C:\Users\....\Template_May.xlsx]
```

*Note files aren't necessarily always in the same order

I want to reach each of these files and assign them to a variable that corresponds to the type of template.

I can do this by doing a a for loop and a long series of if statements

```
for f in files: 
    if "Blanks" in f:
       blank=f 
    if "Stocks" in f:
       stock=f 
    if "May" in f:
       may=f
    if "Coversheet" in f:
       coversheet=f
```

But is there an easier or more pythonic way to achieve this?

Comment: I think a dictionary is the right type to implement your mapping.

Comment: And what if one of your parent folders accidentally contains in its name "Blanks", "May", etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace all your individual variables with a dict, and then you can do something like:

```
TEMPLATE_TYPES = "Blanks", "Stocks", "May", "Coversheet"

files_by_template = {t: [] for t in TEMPLATE_TYPES}
for f in files:
    for t in TEMPLATE_TYPES:
        if t in f:
            files_by_template[t].append(f)
```

Answer (score 2):

First, if this depends only on the file name, you can use that instead of the whole path. You can use regular expressions if the patterns are complex. But in your case and if it's just `Template_TEMPLATENAME.xlsx` you can create a dictionary and map `TEMPLATENAME` to the full name. The code would be something like this:

```py
import os

mapping = dict()

for file in os.listdir():
    mapping[file.replace(".xlsx", "").split("-")[-1]] = file
```

For such a list:

```
Template_A.xlsx
Template_B.xlsx
Template_Foo.xlsx
```

You will have:

```py
{
    "A": "Template_A.xlsx",
    "B": "Template_B.xlsx",
    "Foo": "Template_Foo.xlsx"
}
```